# How can I rotate a transparent png by 45 degrees using imagemagick and keep the new image transparent?

Tags: png, imagemagick, transparency, image-rotation

I have a 16x16 transparent png and I did

```
convert -rotate -45 a.png b.png
```

This rotated it and created a new image b.png which is of size 22x22 and which when I use against a background shows the original image (16x16) rotated with the underlying background but the new filling that came about shows up with a white background.

How is it possible to have the new filling too be transparent?

If that is not possible, than how can I have all the background of the new image be one color?

Answer (score 15):

Use the -background option to specify a transparent color with alpha set to zero:

`convert -background 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' -rotate 45 a.png b.png`

Comment: It should be `convert -background 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' -rotate 45 a.png b.png`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use these options:

```
  -background none
```

Comment: FYI: Depending on how ImageMagick is installed an configured, `-background none' might result in an error like `convert: unable to access configure file `colors.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/589.`. This happens when ImageMagick can't find a config file because of where things are installed. If you run into that, you can use `-background 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was also having the same issue, however I was using the command like so:

```
convert a.png -rotate 45 -background transparent b.png
```

It needed to be:

```
convert -rotate 45 -background transparent a.png b.png
```

So, this actually helped a little, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
convert -rotate 66 -background none c:\input.png c:\output.png
```

works well for me

Answer (score 0):

I used C# to rotate it

```C#
using (MagickImage mimg = new MagickImage(path))
{
  mimg.BackgroundColor = MagickColor.Transparent;
  mimg.Alpha(AlphaOption.Background);
  mimg.AlphaColor = new MagickColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
  mimg.FillColor = new MagickColor(255, 255, 255, 0);
  mimg.Rotate(degree);                    
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the Alpha, AlphaColor and FillColor calls in it. You just need to make sure to set BackgroundColor to transparent *before* rotating.